# Importing .h causes Duplicate Symbol Crash iOS

Tags: ios, import

I am trying to pass along a string from one Class to another in my iOS app.  I have it set up like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // open a alert with an OK and cancel button
    Vimeo *vimeo= [[[Vimeo alloc] initWithNibName:@"Vimeo" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vimeo animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    vimeo.feedAddress = selectedCell.textLabel.text;


}
```

If I don't do

```
#import "Vimeo.h"
```

At the implementation of this class, I get an error that it can't find the property feedAddress in Vimeo.  If I import it, that error goes away, but at runtime, I get the duplicate symbol error.

What is going on?

Comment: Look for places where you are accidentally importing a _.m_ file.

Comment: Update your question with details about the duplicate symbol linking error. And post the offending .h file. Most likely you declared a global variable incorrectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have two files named Vimeo.h on your project, or you don't have two declarations of the class Vimeo